# Does #{variable} in coffeescript only works with " " and not ' '

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I was trying to add some variables into a string like this

```
'-1 #{topDis} -1 -1 #{-topDis} -1 -.8 1 -1 -.8 -1 -1'
```

but was finding that it wasn't working. When I switched to double quotes it would work

```
"-1 #{topDis} -1 -1 #{-topDis} -1 -.8 1 -1 -.8 -1 -1"
```

Should I only be using the " " and not ' ' when writing code for coffeescript? Is this the only time it matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CoffeeScript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#strings):

> Ruby-style string interpolation is included in CoffeeScript. Double-quoted strings allow for interpolated values, using `#{ ... }`, and single-quoted strings are literal.

In other words, if want to use string interpolation, you have to use `"…"` and not `'…'` (or their block-string counter parts). In all other other respects, double-quoted and single-quoted strings are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I looked it up properly but I guess not.